# Absolute Value of an complex ITK Image

Tags: c++, itk

I have an image of type `itk::Image< std::complex<float> >`. Now I want to convert it into an image of type `itk::Image<float>` by calling `std::abs()` on each pixel of the source image.

In the itk documentation I could find [many filters](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen47/html/search.php?query=ComplexTo) to convert complex images. But no absolute filter — which sounds very unlikely to me. Did I miss something?

I thought about using `itk::UnaryFunctorImageFilter`. But this must be inherited, and I need to create a functor around `std::abs` which blows up this ridiculously trivial task to about 20 lines of code.

Comment: there is an AbsImageFilter http://www.itk.org/Doxygen47/html/classitk_1_1AbsImageFilter.html , but in the documentation complex type is not mentioned, so you maybe check that it makes what you expect!

Comment: Unfortunately the AbsImageFiler expects the input pixel type to be convertible to the output pixel type. For some reason it even requires the input type to be [greater than comparable](http://www.itk.org/Doxygen47/html/itkAbsImageFilter_8h_source.html#l00099). Both is not given for complex values.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't check that.  Maybe ComplexToModulusImageAdaptor http://www.itk.org/Doxygen47/html/classitk_1_1ComplexToModulusImageAdaptor.html does what you need?